# TFS Check-In Exception - TF30042 Database is Full

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, version-control, team-foundation-server

I'm trying to check a rather large file into Team Foundation Server (TFS) and getting the following exception.

```
TF30042: Database is Full. Contact your Team Foundation Server administrator.
```

Problem is, I am the administrator. I've checked the database files (both collection and tempdb), and I'm nowhere near the limits in SQL Server 2008 R2, and I've set AutoGrowth to use 8gb chunks and unlimited size on both the database and log files. We have plenty of disk space on the drive that the SQL Server database resides on, and I don't see any size limits in the TFS Administration Console.

From everything I can tell, it seems that I should be fine, what am I missing?

Comment: Did you check both the data and log files?

Comment: Yes, good suggestion, but I did check it, and both data and log files are set to autogrowth of 25%, unlimited growth.

Comment: Another obvious one: tempdb? Really unlikely, but nothing else rings bells for me, and that happened to me once. Or twice. Or, well, you get the idea.

Comment: Yeah, checked, also good, I'm stuck pretty good; there's got to be another somewhere, file size limit for TFS in admin console somewhere or something that I'm missing, but turning up nothing on Google/Bing.

Comment: I wouldn't use 25% for growth, a fixed amount in MB or GB is better; if your log file is large, adding a 25% chunk on the log file can take a while and cause time outs. Check the SQL server for errors in the log.

Comment: While a good recommendation, there's no errors in the log. I did modify the growth to do it in 10 GB blocks now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out, Remote Query Timeout on our SQL Server instance was set to 90 seconds. Uploading almost 3 GB worth of information was causing the query to timeout.

Answer (score 1):

There's another possibility answer for why this error might occur (in the general case), you could be running Express Edition, and your TFS database has reached the maximum database size for the license.

Answer (score 0):

There are four possibilities for this failure:

1. TempDB Log file is not large enough
2. TempDB Data file is not large enough
3. Your CollectionDB log file is not large enough
4. Your collectionDB data file is not large enough

If you go into SQL Management Studio and look at 'Properties' of TempDB (under 'System Databases'), then 'Storage' - what is the size and autogrow parameters set to for both Log and Data?

Then do the same for your collection database. If the log file is not large enough to handle the contents of your large checkin, then SQL will return this error.

Comment: I've already checked all of this, and its specified in my question and above comments.